# What tool was used to create this rails relationship erd diagram?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database, entity, relationships, erd

I have look at the Rails docs and would like to use the same tool to create a relationship diagram like this. does anyone know the tool that was used?

rails erd relationship diagram

[image]

Comment: I think that is created using Photoshop, I knew a tool which made little bit near the design e.g [balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/products/)

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

I think that is created using Photoshop, I knew a tool which made little bit near the design e.g
The [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/products/) Products but it is not free. You can use [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) it's very nice and free. MySQL Workbench is a unified visual tool for database architects, developers, and DBAs. MySQL Workbench provides data modeling, SQL development, and comprehensive administration tools for server configuration, user administration, backup, and much more. MySQL Workbench is available on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X.

Also, [ERDPLUS](https://erdplus.com) is a good tool.